# Filtered water soaked Leica D-Lux 4 repair?

Tags: repair, water, leica

Apologies if this question doesn't fit here (suggested by a moderator)

While on vacation in Las Vegas, the wife decided to pour a bottle of filtered water into her purse and coincidentally, all over our Leica D-Lux 4 camera.

The camera, after a few days of drying out, actually survived and works fine other than the lens and sensor now have water spots on them.

I am fairly mechanically inclined; What are the odds that I can disassemble the camera myself and clean it without having to send it off to a repair shop?

Can anyone recommend a repair shop otherwise that you may have experience with?

Comment: I would start here: http://us.leica-camera.com/service/

Comment: It is really hard for us to gauge "fairly mechanically inclined". Personally, if I tried taking apart a compact like this, I know I would not be able to get it back together properly. This is normally one of those questions where I say "if you have to ask, don't do it"! I would suggest sending it off.

Comment: Fairly mechanically inclined == can solder, read technical schematics and design basic circuits? No problem taking apart laptops / xbox's and repairing / replacing parts. The smallest device I've repaired was a watch and had no problem replacing the LCD panel on an iPhone. Good enough ? :)

Comment: In the old days it would have been easy: just make sure the camera is completely de-powered (batts removed, all caps discharged), soak in *distilled* water for a while to dissolve the spots, etc., pour out the excess, then soak in Freon TF (which will displace the water and evaporate cleanly). But those whinging sunburnt penguins spoiled that approach...

Comment: @StanRogers - Even in the old days, that's a terrible idea. The water soak, followed by the freon soak would dissolve most of the lubrication, and it would then get *everywhere*. You would wind up with a thin coating of grease on all the optics.

Comment: I'd suggest to disassemble it yourself as far as you're "mechanically inclined" and if you get stuck, post clear pictures of the problems you're running into and then we can help.

Comment: Actually, neither water nor TF should have any effect on the high-viscosity silicone lubes used. (And it's still SOP for multi-million-dollar military hardware, including optical instruments, on saltwater ingress.)

Answer (score 3):

This mostly depends on what you define `fairly mechanically inclined` as.

I do electronic design and assembly professionally, and have a hobbyist interest in dissecting and repairing cameras and lenses of all varieties. I have taken apart a significant number of point-and-shoot digital cameras, and I can tell you from experience that there is a large element of chance involved in disassembling and reassembling any point-and-shoot, particularly if you have never taken that particular model apart before.

Basically, many PnS cameras, particularly with retractable lenses, have a very complicated assembly procedure.
Failure to properly follow whatever procedure they require can lead to you easily damaging one of the many, many plastic parts involved in the lens assembly or casing.

Now, if you can find a service manual for the camera, I would say "Go for it!". However, if you're doing your disassembly blind, it's very, **very** easy to damage something because it was assembled in a non-obvious way. One of the worst things to have to deal with is disassembling something, and breaking it along the way. Then, once you have it apart, you see that it had a extremely elegant mechanism for assembly and disassembly that you simply missed, because it was not apparent.

Anyways, it's up to you. If you do decide to try to take the camera apart, make sure you have a clean workspace, and some nice jeweler's screw-drivers, and a good pair of tweezers.

Comment: Also, adding to the last paragraph, **use a tray** or other surface that stops small screws and parts from rolling away etc.

Answer (score 1):

Water damage is usually about short-circuiting electronics.

You do not have this problem, since you said after drying out, the camera works.

However in digital cameras, a sensor can also be water-damaged. This, however, cannot be repaired easily. It is not about electricity conductivity, its purely about water seeping into the sensor creating **optical** artifacts, even if the sensor is working.

The sensor, is also one of the most expensive component so repair charge is expected to be high.

As far as I know, unless you can remove the sensor, dry it so completely that there is no remaining water, or that the water particles do not **optically** affect the image quality, you are, unfortunately, looking at a costly repair or a replacement altogether.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are talking about here. Sensor packages are almost universally hermetically sealed. It seems like you're confusing the lens assembly and the actual sensor.